# Openvpn and IPV6: how to configure it without knowing the server's IPV6 address

Tags: ipv6

I'm using **openvpn** to connect to a network through a **VPN** and I use a **ovpn** file which is the following:

```
dev tap
persist-tun
persist-key
cipher AES-128-CBC
auth SHA1
tls-client
client
resolv-retry infinite
remote smthvpn06.somedomain.com 1194 udp
lport 0
auth-user-pass
ns-cert-type server

<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEmzCCA4OgAwIBAgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADCBkDELMAkGA1UEBhMCVVMx
             ....
QGWNykAXUSbqJM2NpIKi+6iyc+NNtijYMCjMPQeqvw==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
Eh0CPLYgWyRMWwc/8/rhrlNtrsJ2H8U1IhhJcwFgbJ+4/klCAUhcdwWKgKF8sfgr

MI6nkXW5lAHRjNBmpY2jrtH3d2XXgGrVIV52iNmhPeCOWwxqIlcROuCydxJy
/7edS1Y3
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDgn65ZGarhcM8A

mT3KHe9+mhHCBCP3Cfm1NeEm
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key   
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
7af112a9ad39a604b3c4d90c707888e7

-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
 key-direction 1
```

I know the network to which I can connect with the VPN have several IPV6 interfaces. And I would like to connect to them.

**Problem:** I don't know neither the IPV6 addresses of those hosts, neither the **IPV6** address of the server.

So, any hint to find it out would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nslookup -q=aaaa smthvpn-6.somedomain.com
```

In a windows environment this will return the IPV6 Address associated with the domain name given.

**nslookup** is used to query name servers for their DNS Records.

```
nslookup [-option] [name | -] [server]
```

-q is the querytype option:

```
-querytype=value or -q=value
```

The query tpe command changes the type of information your query retrieves. If you're running the command in a Windows environment the query types are listed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490738.aspx

Using the aaaa option queries the target server for the ipv6 address associated with the specified DNS record.

Comment: Thanks, but **-q=aaaa** what is it for ?

Comment: "aaaa" is the DNS record type for mapping hostnames to IPv6 addresses